# Cannot switch user 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm running on a Macbook pro. Most of the times, not always, the "switch user" functionality fails. There are 2 outcomes:

1. My laptop goes to sleep.
2. My laptop shows me the login screen of my current user.

Anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  Here are my specs:
Ubuntu 18.4.1 LTS, 12gb RAM, Intel® Core™ i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4, Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2), GNOME 3.28.2, OS type 64-bit.  I almost always experience the 2nd scenario.  My users are both Admins and have the same password.  I separate them for different dev environments for software developement.